# JavaFX Charts: Change the ChartType of the XYChart at runtime?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to change the type of chart that is being displayed for e.g.
`LineChart` extends `XYChart` and `AreaChart` also extends `XYChart`.
Can I switch the `LineChart` drawn to `AreaChart` at runtime?

> ```
> For XYChart,
>
> Direct Known Subclasses:
> AreaChart, BarChart, BubbleChart, LineChart, ScatterChart, StackedAreaChart, StackedBarChart
> ```

Any help would be great!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Charts show information according to the list of data, and according to the settings of chart and of 2 axes. Charts don't modify list of data.

So, you have to put list of data into 2 charts, make 2 pairs (or 1 pair, if applicable) of axes, and phisically exchange chart at specific location in scenegraph.

It theory, it should work. If it doesn't work in practise - it should be investigated (possibly, it is a bug). But there is no trouble to show info in several charts and replace charts.